Function of two random variables: specific example
The Problem
I have two random variables. The first random variable, $\Theta$, has CDF
$F_\Theta(\theta) = \sin^2(\theta), \theta \in [0,\pi/2]$.
The second random variable, $\Phi$, has CDF
$F_\Phi(\phi) = \frac{\phi}{2\pi}, \phi \in [0,2\pi]$
The corresponding PDFs are easily found as
$f_\Theta(\theta) = \sin(2\theta)$, $f_\Phi(\phi)=\frac{1}{2\pi}$.
The problem is to compute (analytically), (edit: PDF/CDF of) the random variable
$X = \sin(\Theta)\cos(\Phi)$
The motivation
I am doing radiation heat transfer monte-carlo and rays are generated according to a Lambertian emitter. The ray is defined in the x-y plane according to
$\vec{u} = [u_x,u_y,u_z] = [\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi),\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),\cos(\theta)]$
I am curious as to the analytic expression for the probability distribution of the x and y components of the vector. Mostly because after applying some transformations to a set of generated vectors, one axial component should still be distributed according to $X$. Although I can check with a histogram that the sampled values do in fact match the expected distribution (by checking against the original histogram of e.g. $u_x$), I'm now curious as to the analytic expression.
My Attempt
Let $U = \sin(\Theta)$, we have
$F_U(u) = P(U<u) = P(\sin(\theta)<u) = P(\theta< \sin^{-1}(u)) F_\Theta(\sin^{-1}(u)) = \sin^2(\sin^{-1}(u))$
$F_U(u)=u^2, u\in [0,1], f_U(u) = 2u$
Let $V = \cos(\Phi)$, we have
$F_V(v) = P(V<v) = P(\cos(\phi)<v) = P(\phi < \cos^{-1}(v))$
This is a bit trickier due to periodicity, but it comes out to
$F_V(v) = P(\cos^{-1}(v)<\phi<2\pi-\cos^{-1}(v)) = F_\Phi(2\pi-\cos^{-1}(v)-F_\Phi(\cos^{-1}(v)) = \frac{2\pi-\cos^{-1}(v)}{2\pi}-\frac{\cos^{-1}(v)}{2\pi}$
$F_V(v) = 1-\frac{\cos^{-1}(v)}{\pi}, v\in [-1,1], f_V(v) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-v^2}}$
Now here's where I get stuck, I want the PDF/CDF of $X = UV$. Following the steps from Wikipedia page for this problem, I obtain:
$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_U(u)f_V(x/u)\frac{1}{|u|}du$
Since $u \in [0,1]$, $f_U(u) = 0$ if $u<0$ or $u>1$, and the expression becomes
$f_X(x) = \int_0^1 f_U(u)f_V(x/u)\frac{1}{u}du$.
Substituting, we get
$f_X(x) = \int_0^1 2u\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-(x/u)^2}}\frac{1}{u}du = \int_0^1\frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{1-(x/u)^2}}du$
Which is all great but this integral diverges is not real, as for small $u$, the square root is negative. Similarly, switching the functions so that
$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_V(v)f_U(x/v)\frac{1}{|v|}dv$
has not gotten me anywhere.
Any thoughts on where I've gone wrong?

Just a note: you cannot "compute random variable ", rather its cdf or pdf...

A direct method is to use:
$$
\begin{align}
f_X(\xi) &= \langle\delta(X-\xi)\rangle\\
&= \frac1{2\pi}\int \delta(\sin\theta\cos\phi-\xi)\sin(2\theta)d\theta d\phi \\
&= \frac1\pi\int \delta(z\cos\phi-\xi)zdzd\phi \\
&= \frac1\pi\int_{x^2+y^2<1}\delta(x-\xi)dxdy\\
&= \frac1\pi\int_{-\sqrt{1-\xi^2}}^{\sqrt{1-\xi^2}}dy\\
&= \frac{2\sqrt{1-\xi^2}}\pi
\end{align}
$$
which you can check numerically. Geometrically, $z=\sin\theta$ the height and I switched to “abstract” cartesian coordinates:
$$
x=z\cos\phi\quad y=z\sin\phi
$$
Intuitively, $X$ is distributed like the $x$ coordinate of a point uniformly distributed on the unit disk. You can also find the cdf geometrically:
$$
F_X(x)=\frac12+\frac{x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\arcsin x}\pi
$$
